# rails and solr: cannot start solr on el capitan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails

I am unable to start solr on el capitan. Any ideas?

I tried the suggestions at [sunspot issue](https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/issues/683)
already.

```
$ bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:run --trace
** Invoke sunspot:solr:run (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute sunspot:solr:run
2016-06-15 10:06:20.632:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.8.v20121106
2016-06-15 10:06:20.654:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:Deployment monitor /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@colaborator/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/solr/contexts at interval 0
2016-06-15 10:06:20.659:INFO:oejd.DeploymentManager:Deployable added: /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@colaborator/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/solr/contexts/solr.xml
2016-06-15 10:06:20.727:INFO:oejw.WebInfConfiguration:Extract jar:file:/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@colaborator/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/solr/webapps/solr.war!/ to /private/var/folders/5f/zzf610cj0xjd82ytn7mpr6700000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8982-solr.war-_solr-any-/webapp
2016-06-15 10:06:21.709:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:NO JSP Support for /solr, did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
Null identity service, trying login service: null
Finding identity service: null
2016-06-15 10:06:21.746:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,file:/private/var/folders/5f/zzf610cj0xjd82ytn7mpr6700000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8982-solr.war-_solr-any-/webapp/},/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@colaborator/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/solr/webapps/solr.war
2016-06-15 10:06:21.747:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,file:/private/var/folders/5f/zzf610cj0xjd82ytn7mpr6700000gn/T/jetty-0.0.0.0-8982-solr.war-_solr-any-/webapp/},/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@colaborator/gems/sunspot_solr-2.1.1/solr/webapps/solr.war
2016-06-15 10:06:22.134:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Started SocketConnector@0.0.0.0:8982
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question:

My team had java 1.7 and they were all fine, I downgraded my java from 1.8 to 1.7  Solr is working fine now.

Hopefully this should help others who run in to the same issue.